# before playing a video in vimeo, I want to add a 5-10 seconds advertisement

Tags: video, vimeo, vimeo-api, vimeo-player

I have a query regarding the advertisements in vimeo video. I want to know that is it possible to play a 5-10 seconds of advertisement, before the main video starts in vimeo player?

This is the same functionality as we see commonly in youtube video, before a video in youtube any advertisement comes, so similar to this, can we do it in vimeo?

I want to upload that advertisement from the admin panel of my website through the vimeo API.

Comment: You can use javascript for showing div with big z-index for few seconds.

Comment: where is cakephp then?

Answer (score 0):

I have checked this and I found this link -

https://vimeo.com/help/faq/vimeo-membership/vimeo-pro. It says -

"Please note that the Vimeo player doesn’t support pre-roll, post-roll, or overlay ads."